# Reference swagger.yaml definitions from the Java API

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a Spring Boot application that uses the Swagger API to auto-generate Swagger documentation. There is an old swagger.yaml file that contains a lot of object definitions. Instead of re-writing these in Java classes I would like to access the swagger.yaml file and use the existing definitions. Is this somehow possible?

Something along the lines of:

```
@Schema(name = "name", description = "description", ref = definition from swagger.yaml)
private SomeClass someClass;
```